# How can I make this Javascript forEach More efficient?

Tags: javascript

The entire purpose of this code is to arrange the data that was dumped into CommRef_ into the required structure of "ResObj".

The issue is, some of the "CommRef" arrays can have as many as 35,000+ elements in them. This causes the operation to take upwords of 13 seconds on current hardware.

So I'm double checking for ways to make this more efficient.

Any Suggestions??

P.S. The only place where large numbers are handled is in the //Build Row Array Loop

**Before Structure**

```
{ "TableName": [ 
  { "PartNumber": "Widget00001", "PartName": WidgetName },
  { "PartNumber": "Widget00002", "PartName": WidgetName },
  ect.....,
  { "PartNumber": "Widget35001", "PartName": WidgetName }
]
```

**After Structure Desired**

```
{
  "DataSources": [
    {
      "Id": "PartNumbers",
      "DeletedRows": [],
      "NewRows": [],
      "Rows": [
        [
          "00001",
          "WidgetName"
        ],
        [
          "00002",
          "WidgetName"
        ],
         [
          "35001",
          "WidgetName"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code**

```
RefDataTables.forEach(function(t,ti){
  try{
    if(CommRef_[t]){
      if (CommRef_[t].hasOwnProperty("error")){
        response.statusCode = 500;
        responseBody = responseBody + "\n" + JSON.stringify(CommRef_[t].error);
      }else{
        response.statusCode = 200;

        //Build Row Array
        rowsObj = {"Rows":[]};
        CommRef_[t].forEach(function(d,di){
          rowsObj.Rows.push(_.values(CommRef_[t][di]));
        });

        //Build NewRows Array

        //Build Deleted Rows Array

        //Append DataSources Array
        ResObj.DataSources.push({"Id": t, "Rows":rowsObj.Rows, "NewRows":[], "DeletedRows":[]});
      }
    }else{
      ResObj.DataSources.push({"Id": t, "Rows":[], "NewRows":[], "DeletedRows":[]});
    }
  }
  catch(err){
    responseBody = responseBody + "\n" + JSON.stringify("Ref Data Object Build Error " + err);
  }
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there is some looping that you repeat

Comment: It would help a ***lot*** if you gave us an example of the structure before, the structure after, and explained the transformation.

Comment: Maybe not having 35,000 elements in your array to begin with would be a good starting point. If this is from a db can you not return a more refined data set?

Comment: @Andy   Unfortunately that is the "refined" data list.   It is a parts list.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder   The Before structure is like this:   {
  "TableName": [
    {
      "PartNumber": "Widget35000",
      "PartName": Widget
    },{
      "PartNumber": "Widget35001",
      "PartName": Widget
    }]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  And the After structure is as shown in the script for the ResObj.

Comment: @Andy  I also took your advice and posted it to codereview.stackexchange.com   I was unfamiliar with that resource.